# How to get value of latlng from L.CircleMarker to popup?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using following code for displaying latlng value in popup.

```
var gj = L.geoJson(geoJson, { style: function (feature) {return {color: "#00f"}; }, pointToLayer : function (featureData, latlng) {
            var popupOptions = {maxWidth: 200};
            var popupContent = latlng;
            return L.circleMarker(latlng, {radius: 4}).bindPopup(popupContent,popupOptions);
        }});

        geoJsonOverlay.addLayer(gj);
```

Reference - https://gist.github.com/alexgleith/7112515

This doesn't gives me what I need. I don't know why. What's wrong in this? How can I get coordinates in popup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me ...

```
pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
   var popup = L.popup().setContent("latlng: " + latlng);
   var marker = L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
   marker.bindPopup(popup);
   return marker;               
}
```